# Avoid a database file to delete

Tags: c#, winforms, security

I have created a software with C# on windows platform.
So it uses an access database file which it is embedded in bin folder of application.
How can I prevent windows users from deleting the database file in windows exloprer ?

They can navigate to bin folder and then select the database and press delete on their keyboard...
What should am I do ? 
Hiding the bin folder or the folder which contains database is not secure I think , because they can un-hide that...

Comment: You would use Windows file permissions for this, which isn't really a programming question.

Comment: You can't (and shouldn't) try to prevent the user deleting any files. If you need this kind of security it should be done form an IT administration perspective - not via your software

Comment: There isn't really any good way, in the end if the application can access it, the user will as well.

Comment: You could use a background service that maintains a lock on the file, but is this use-case really necessary? Ultimately, it should be up to the user/admin to decide what files can remain on the system, not your app. Your app should just handle the use case where a database isn't found.

Comment: Good adivce keyboardP [[[backup]]]

Comment: I'm pretty sure that trying to stop a user from deleting a file on THEIR machine would classify you as malware. :)

Comment: some user of this forum , just move their hand on close button or down vote.... please take look at the filled aspect of glass not the empty one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The computer belongs to the user. You shouldn't be trying to prevent users from doing what they want to their computers.

If the database is a critical piece of the application, then it isn't any different from the user navigating to the program folder and pressing delete on your main executable - if they do things like that, they should expect to have to reinstall the application.

So your program can show a nice message if it sees the database is missing, like "This application is no longer in a usable state. Please reinstall the application."